# How to get nested types in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, json, scala, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-api

I have the following document:

```
{
  "_index" : "testdb",
  "_type" : "artWork",
  "_id" : "0",
  "_version" : 4,
  "found" : true,
  "_source":{"uuid":0,
             "StatusHistoryList":[
        {
        "ArtWorkDate":"2015-08-28T15:52:03.030+05:00",
        "ArtworkStatus":"ACTIVE"
        },
        {
        "ArtWorkDate":"2015-08-28T15:52:03.030+05:00",
        "ArtworkStatus":"INACTIVE"
        }
             ]
}
```

and here is the mapping of the document:

```
{
  "testdb" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "artWork" : {
        "properties" : {
          "StatusHistoryList" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "ArtWorkDate" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "store" : true
              },
              "ArtworkStatus" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "store" : true
              }
            }
          },

          "uuid" : {
            "type" : "integer",
            "store" : true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to access the values of `StatusHistoryList`. I got null values if I do it like this:

```
val get = client.prepareGet("testdb", "artWork", Id.toString()).setOperationThreaded(false)
        .setFields("uuid",,"StatusHistoryList.ArtworkStatus","StatusHistoryList.ArtWorkDate","_source")

        .execute()
        .actionGet()
  var artworkStatusList= get.getField("StatusHistoryList.ArtworkStatus").getValues.toArray()

var artWorkDateList= get.getField("StatusHistoryList.ArtWorkDate").getValues.toArray()
```

then I got null values from the code but my document contains the values then I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367884/elasticsearch-java-client-search-nested-field-not-working)
so after that i tried to do it like this

```
 var smap = get.getSource.get("StatusHistoryList").asInstanceOf[Map[String,Object]]
```

but then a `ClassCastException` is thrown

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

Please help me how can I get the values of `StatusHistoryList` 's  `ArtworkStatus` and `ArtWorkDate` values please guide me I will be very thankfull to you.

Answer (score 0):

You have almost derived the solution. The GET request has retrieved the response but the problem is in parsing the response.

Let's see the problem. Below is the document that the elastic search returns as source

```
{
    "uuid":0,
    "StatusHistoryList":[
       {
          "ArtWorkDate":"2015-08-28T15:52:03.030+05:00",
          "ArtworkStatus":"ACTIVE"
       },
       {
          "ArtWorkDate":"2015-08-28T15:52:03.030+05:00",
          "ArtworkStatus":"INACTIVE"
       }
    ]
}
```

When we do `get.getSource.get("StatusHistoryList")` it returns List ArtWork objects and not a Map. That is the reason for the `classCastException` exception.

So if you cast the response to list of objects your problem will be solved.

But this would not be an ideal solution. Some of the libraries like [Jackson-Faterxml](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) does the job for you. Using the fasterxml library you can bind the json to equivalent POJO Object.